# Changing the template hierarchy

Tags: php, theme-development, themes, page-template

Is there an easy way to change the WP default template hierarchy?

For instance;

Say I want to change my theme directory structure so that it completely changes from the Template Hierarchy suggested here based upon conditionals:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

If I wanted to make sure that for all page types (`is_single()` `is_home()` etc) it always opens one template file which then instigates my own pattern to provide the output?

Thanks very much!

Comment: don't make duplicate questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196986/changing-wordpress-template-hierarchy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this filter

```
function wpse_63614_restructure_template_hierarchy( $template ){
    return get_template_directory().'/filename.php';
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse_63614_restructure_template_hierarchy' );
```

The filename would be the file you would want to call in your theme folder. For child themes you would use `get_stylesheet_directory` instead.

**EDIT:**

Or as suggested by Chip Bennett and what I too feel would be better; you can use the `template_redirect` hook in the following manner. The priority can be set accordingly if required.

```
function wpse_63614_restructure_template_hierarchy(){
    include( get_template_directory().'/filename.php' );
    exit;
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_63614_restructure_template_hierarchy' );
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua where would this go? In my theme activation?

Comment: in your theme's `functions.php`

Comment: This is the right approach, but I would suggest using the `template_redirect` hook.

Comment: Yup just had a look at the `template-loader.php` once again. Don't know how did I miss that one. Will add that too in the answer.